# Will wait() calls be executed in a predictable order?

Tags: c, fork, posix, wait

Suppose I had the following code:

```
pid_t pid0, pid1;

pid0 = fork();
if (!pid0) {
    pid1 = fork();

    if (!pid1) { // p2
        /* do something */
        return; 
    } else {    // p1
        wait(NULL);
        printf("p1 done\n");
        return;
   }
} 

// p0
wait(NULL):
printf("p0 done\n");
```

Is the order of the print statements deterministic, or will it be up to the will of the CPU? In practice, it seems to be the same every time, but the docs for `wait()` make it seem like it should be random.

EDIT: I've thought about it some more, and I'm wondering if it's always in that order because p0 doesn't have p2 as a child process; that's p1's child. So "p0 done" won't print until p1 finishes waiting for its child, p2. So, I suppose the real question is does `wait()` wait for children's children, or just processes one "generation" away

Comment: All you can say is it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Use explicit synchronisation if you want a guaranteed sequence of execution => If you don’t use synchrronization then you don’t get a guaranteed sequence. Depending on a non-guaranteed sequence which very occasionally happens in a different way can cause very occasional inexplicable/irreproducible bugs.

Comment: `wait` only waits for the process's direct children, not grandchildren.

Comment: Which aspect of the documentation on `wait()` makes you think that it is indeterminate? You've coded it so that it is determinate, AFAICS. The "`p1 done`" message can't appear until p2 has exited. The message must be flushed before p1 terminates, almost regardless of what happens after p1 returns. A possible exception would be if the output is neither line buffered nor unbuffered and the p1 code after the return does an `_exit()` or `quick_exit()` — then the p1 message won't appear). Otherwise, p0 is waiting on p1; the output from p1 must appear before the "`p0 done`" message appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Process 0 will always wait for process 1, because that's the only child it has.
And process 1 will always wait for process 2, because that's the only child it has.

Process 0 won't return from `wait` until process 1 exits, which means that process 1 has already printed its message, because it does that before it exits.

So in this case process 0 cannot continue until after the message has been printed.